# Redirect to page after receiving server response 200 for auth in React-Redux project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

Really, struggling with this the past several days. Converting a `react-router v2` project over to `react-router-dom v4`.

Originally redirect was done in `./actions/index.js` with `browserHistory.push('/home');` which no longer works in `react-router-dom v4` unless you create a context which is "experimental" and isn't really supported, so you are supposed to do it in your components/containers with `withRoute`. At least, that is my understanding if you want to redirect in actions file and not a component/container.

Anyway, being a newb it is taking me a while. Most of the tutorials I am not finding useful since they don't really take into account waiting for a server response and I am just not sure where the redirect is supposed to go in my component.

What I currently have you have to submit twice to be redirected: 1) to `PUT` credentials to auth API; 2) to take the response saved in localStorage and use that to validate the redirect.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
// ./containers/authentication/signin.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { signinUser, authError } from '../../actions/authentication';

const renderInput = field => {
    const { input, type } = field;
    return (
        <div>
            <input {...input} type={type} className='form-control' />
        </div>
    );
}

class Signin extends Component {
    handleFormSubmit({ username, password }) {
        this.props.signinUser({ username, password });
        if (localStorage.getItem('status') === '200') {
            this.props.history.push('/home');
        }   
    }

    renderAlert() {
        if (this.props.errorMessage) {
            return (
                <div className="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>Oops!</strong> {this.props.errorMessage}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Username:</label>
                    <Field name='username' type='username' component={renderInput} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <Field name='password' type='password' component={renderInput} />
                </div>
                {this.renderAlert()}
                <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
            </form>

        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { errorMessage: state.auth.error };
}

Signin = connect(mapStateToProps, { signinUser, authError })(Signin);
Signin = reduxForm({
    form: 'signin'
})(Signin);
export default withRouter(Signin);
```

---

```
// ./actions/authentication/index.js

import axios from 'axios';
import { ROOT_URL } from '../../../config/settings/secrets.json';

export const AUTH_USER = 'auth_user';
export const UNAUTH_USER = 'unauth_user';
export const AUTH_ERROR = 'auth_error';

export function signinUser({ username, password }) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/api/auth/token/`, { username, password })
            .then(response => {
            dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
            localStorage.setItem('status', response.status);            
            })
            .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            dispatch(authError('Bad Login Info'));
        });
    }
}

export function authError(error) {
    return {
        type: AUTH_ERROR,
        payload: error
    };
}

export function signoutUser() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    return { type: UNAUTH_USER };
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `window.location = '/home';`? In case it's a redirect and you don't need your application/state/components to keep their state - there shouldn't be any problem with that

Comment: That does accomplish what I am after. However, it refreshes the whole window, which isn't the end of the world, but the entire application has the same static header and footer. The transition "looks nicer" with it just rendering the new component instead of refreshing the whole window. Sorry, didn't think to bring it up because I am not there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`react-router-redux`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) to dispatch `push`, `replace` and similar actions. Here is the link to the [other docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) (its a bit older but there are more info about API)

Comment: Thanks! The link got me started, but I did have to consult this article to get things mostly straightened out. https://medium.com/@notrab/getting-started-with-create-react-app-redux-react-router-redux-thunk-d6a19259f71f. Also, don't use `<BrowserRouter>` with `<ConnectedRouter>`. Just use the latter. That was the last issue I had to sort out with URL changing but component not loading.